# Select All tables / not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have the following master & child tables (All of them require ADD/EDIT/DELETE)

```
tblSchool
tblStudent
tblClass
tblTests

|
> tblSchoolClass
> tblClassStudent
> tblStudentTest
```

So, while specifying a new ADO.net Data Entity model, **Do i need to select ALL the tables or group and select them** (*creating 2 or more models in the process*) ?

*(Disclaimer : ASP.net MVC newbie)*

Comment: Select all tables and put them to single EDMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ladislav as answered, select all your tables and put them in a single model.   If you have the relationships (primary and foreign keys) setup correctly in the database, these will be created in your entity model as well.

Creating two models would serve no purpose other than to make your life more difficult.  I have used separate models only when I am dealing with multiple databases.  In your case, it sounds like you only have one database.